# The custom jQuery componet shows incorrectly when I add a attribute data-role="page" to the tag <div> that I wrap this component with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I made a modification from here: https://github.com/jsdev/mobile508datepicker
The original version's demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Accessible-jQuery-Date-Picker-For-jQuery-Mobile-mobile508datepicker/

After modifying the custom componet, it shows correctly when I just wrap it with the `<div id="home">` tag. Here is a link to my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jiiarong/1kcbrsxn/
(You can click on the "Please select..." and test in the right-bottom area)

But when I just wrapped it with the `<div id="home" data-role="page">` tag, i.e. with the attribute data-role="page", it looks something wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/jiiarong/3jzb9sb0/
(You can click on the "Please select..." and test in the right-bottom area)

- It only show the text "Close" instead of the "cross" image.
- It loses the "Set" button at the bottom.
- I can't scroll it and select a item on it.

The codes of two links to the jsFiddle only have a difference in ONE line, that is, `<div id="home">` tag's attribute: data-role="page". The codes in other lines are the same. I can't figure it out why it goes wrong when I wrapped it with the `<div id="home" data-role="page">` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out.
First I compare the original component [here](https://github.com/jsdev/mobile508datepicker) with modified component [at my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jiiarong/3jzb9sb0/).

original component > [jquery.mobile508datepicker.js](https://github.com/jsdev/mobile508datepicker/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile508datepicker.js) > line 25 ~ 30

```
buildEl = function () {
        $('body').append($el);
        $el.trigger('create');
        $el.popup();
        return $el;
    },
```

[my incorrect modified component](http://jsfiddle.net/jiiarong/3jzb9sb0/) > line 58 ~ 65

```
buildEl = function () {
                $('body').append($el);
                $el.popup();
                return $el;
            },
```

After I added a line "$el.trigger('create');" at line 61 of [my modified component](http://jsfiddle.net/jiiarong/3jzb9sb0/) , it worked!

I'm relieved to solve the immediate problem, although I still don't know why the component without "$el.trigger('create');" act correctly when it wasn't wrapped  with the  tag.